How to stop PGAdmin 4 auto detecting a ghost instance? MAC OS
I had Postgresql 15 (macOS) installed and did a complete uninstall, including the data directory and all old copies of PgAdmin. There are no environment variables specific to this or any other legacy Postgres installation.
I recently installed Postgresql 16 and PgAdmin 4
v8.10 using the EnterpriseDB installer. When I run PgAdmin 4 it automatically detects a postgresql instance named 15 - although the details say it's actually my v16 instance with the same port number and password etc. The only difference is that it points to a non-existent old data directory.
tell me what's the problem?
-remove pgAdmin 4 in application support.
-delete ~/.pgadmin
-install postgreSQL 15 and uninstall it again

pgAdmin simply reads the /etc/postgres-reg.ini file. Please fix this file.
